# How would I go about making a 3 digit pin generator?

Tags: python-3.x, passwords

Ok so what im trying to do is make somthing that generates 3 digit pins

so like:

000
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
110
210
Etc

but something that generates that with python?
I've done some research but they are all for ethical hacking I just want to make something that can be used in a game where there are two sides, one makes a password for the 3 digit "vault". and one team has to use the device to find the password

Comment: You want to generate 3 digit number randomly or exhaustively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 3 digit pin is just a number from 0 to 999, which can be generated with `random.randrange(1000)`.  To format it with leading zeroes, you can use python's string formatting - `"%03d" % n` will give 000 if n is 0, 012 if n is 12, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string
n=100            #number of outputs required
def randomGenerator(stringlength=3):
      number=string.digits
return ''.join(random.choice(number) for i in range(stringlength))
for i in range(n):
    print("pin is",randomGenerator())
```

Kindly take care of Indentations